# Generate installer including Jar File and Mysql db

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jar

I have created a java application in eclipse, and I intend to create an installer for the project.

For this I have created a jar file of the application, but I'm using the mysql database localhost.

How can I generate Jar File with Mysql db embedded into it .
I exported the database and added this .db file and jar inside Installer and created the product.
But my doubt is I have used below code

```
    String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sample";

    try {
        // Establish the connection.
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "root", "");
```

but instead localhost ,What should I give?
I wants to run this product in another machine,(independently).
Is there anything can be done to integrate mysql with in the jar file of my created project?

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks and regards

Comment: MySql isn't really designed for this. Instead consider a proper embedded database such as H2 or SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MySQL I recommend you to use use [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

H2 database doesn't require database server to run on user's machine but insteads runs on the same JVM as your application (it's kind of "library", [read more about embedded databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database))

H2 shares a lot of the same syntax with MySQL so if it's a simple application chances are that you wan't have to change anything in your SQL queries to work with H2. Additionally you can set H2 to work in "MySQL compatibility mode" (see: [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility)) to make the migration easier.

Comment: Hi I tried using H2 database by adding h2*.jar to the classpath of myproject.I created a runnable jar ,I was able to fetch deatils from the database.                                               But the problem is when I tried to run the same jar in another machine ,it is not working....Kindly plz advice me